# Распознавание дубликатов видео

Tags: алгоритм, видео, распознавание

Ищу open-source проект для решения следующей задачи:

Дано множество видеофайлов, среди которых нужно найти одинаковые. При этом одинаковые видеозаписи в разном качестве и под разными кодеками тоже должны детектиться. То есть сравнение по хэшу или по длине не подойдет, нужен глубокий анализ.

Лучшее, что я сейчас нашел -- это [SOTU](http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~wzhao2/sotu.htm), но его исходники закрыты.

Так же буду благодарен за ссылки на хорошую теорию по этой теме.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант от себя:

если транскодер ничего не делает с видео, а только ужимает его (т.е. таймлайн остается равный), то можно сделать так (ну чисто теоретически):

- разделить видео на несколько кадров (сколько душе угодно)
- сравнить эти кадры

Методы сравнения изображений можно подчерпнуть тут:

http://compsciclub.ru/node/2003